# Better management of long conditional formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, conditional-formatting

I have a long and unwieldy formatting condition, currently it's doing 9 function calls, and I'd like to make it even larger.

My trouble is that it's getting increasingly difficult to manage all the parenthesis.

Is there some functionality in spreadsheets to make editing this easier than the tiny text-field used to input conditional formatting?

For context, here's my current formula, though the question is intended to be broader than this particular formula.

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(IFERROR(MATCH(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1)), E$3:E$22, 0), 999) + 2, COLUMN() + 3)) + 1`

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a built-in functionality in Google Sheets to make it easier to edit complex conditional formatting formulas.

One workaround is to write the formula in a regular cell, then copy it to the conditional formatting formula textbox.

Another workaround is to use the [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/conditional-formatting) or an addon that use it.